# What is the difference between calling and returning a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, closures

I am experimenting with some express routes and I am attempting to do something like this:

```
route.get('/guest', GuestHandler.getAll)
```

and 'getAll' would be defined as so (doesn't work):

```
GuestHandler.getAll = function() {
     return function(req, res) {
          res.send('hello world');
     }
};
```

This works:

```
GuestHandler.getAll = function(req, res) {
     res.send('hello world');
}
```

How can I make something like the former work without explicitly doing the latter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make something like the former work without explicitly doing the latter?

You'd have to **call** `getAll` in order to get the function it returns:

```
route.get('/guest', GuestHandler.getAll())
// Change is here ---------------------^^
```

Comment: Oh yes! That's all I was missing. Thanks for the help!